# go-git: Create short hash (a83ad00 instead of a83ad004b3c5...)

Tags: go, go-git

I am using [go-git](https://github.com/go-git/go-git) and I would like to print the short hash.

I mean, for example "a83ad00" instead of "a83ad004b3c5971a194ba86b96fe313b94bbcde7".

I looked at the source code of got-git, but could not find a corresponding function.

How to get the short "partial" hash?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you substring it? I do not see any from the [API docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5@v5.4.2)

```golang
full := repo.Head().Hash().String()
short := full[0:8]
```

Comment: But this could fail, if there is already a different commit with the same short hash. AFAIK this simple way does not work.